# server error message [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:

Tags: node.js, reactjs

### I'm getting a error message on my server saying:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const knex = require('knex');
const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

 const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host : '127.0.0.1',
      user : 'postgres',
      password : '',
      database : 'smart-brain'
    }
  });

 const app = express();

 app.use(cors());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {res.send(database.users) })

 app.post('/signin',  signin.handleSignin(db,bcrypt))

 app.post('/register', (req, res) => {register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) })

 app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res)=> {profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)})

 app.put('/image', (req, res) => {image.handleImage(req, res, db)})

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

Comment: how is this related to `reactjs` tag?

Comment: I'm using react to build my project

Comment: check your return statement of your routes. making sure res.send(variable) or res.json(variable) are not empty or undefined.

Comment: I looked at the error in the browser its saying my fetch not working.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a database credentials issue.  It looks like you have "" for a password and you're using postgres for you database.  You might want to recheck that your superuser(postgres) does not have a password or [reset](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/)
it.

You might also check to see if you have coded any conditional process.env USER and PASSWORD variables in your app that.  If you have then you will have to assign those variables in your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably related to the database config file. For mine, I had the password wrongly imported from config. Had to add a `toString()` method to my password's `config.get()` method.

Here is what my knexfile looks like after adding toString() to my password

```
{
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    database: 'barhalt',
    user: 'root',
    password: config.get('db_user_password').toString()
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your insights. Here are posting rules you may not be aware of: All code, data, & error messages must be embedded as plain text, not as images. Text in images cannot be copy-pasted into editors or search engines. Also text in images can be difficult to read, especially on mobile devices, and can consume undue mobile data. Additionally, since the "exact code necessary to solve the OP's issue" isn't embeded, it's considered a Comment, but Not an Answer. Please `edit` accordingly to avoid deletion by SO. More info on posting guidelines can be found at StackOverflow.com/help